# What to pass as parameter in permission while integrating vk ios sdk in ios app?

Tags: ios, iphone, oauth, vk

I am working on a *iphone application* where i have to integrate [vk.com](http://vk.com) russian social networking site. I have integrated the vk `iOS SDK`s downloaded [from Github](https://github.com/AYastrebov/Vkontakte-iOS-SDK). In below method I passed the `my application id` as `app id` but I’m a bit confused about the permission parameter. I have searched through lot of sites including the vk developer site but was unable to find solution what to pass as permission parameter.

```
"[VKSession openSessionWithAppId:APP_ID permissions:PERMISSIONS handler:^(NSError *error)"
```

While i am executing my app i am getting the Error as follows:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain 
  Code=-999 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)"
  UserInfo=0x6e7d980 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=4069809&scope=friends&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&display=touch&response_type=token, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=4069809&scope=friends&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&display=touch&response_type=token}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the permissions user have to pass the details he want to use the login users like @"EmailId,,FriendList,Profile Details".

Answer (score 3):

You can use constants listed in VKPermissions.h

```
NSString *const VK_PER_NOTIFY = @"notify";
NSString *const VK_PER_FRIENDS = @"friends";
NSString *const VK_PER_PHOTOS = @"photos";
NSString *const VK_PER_AUDIO = @"audio";
NSString *const VK_PER_VIDEO = @"video";
NSString *const VK_PER_DOCS = @"docs";
NSString *const VK_PER_NOTES = @"notes";
NSString *const VK_PER_PAGES = @"pages";
NSString *const VK_PER_STATUS = @"status";
NSString *const VK_PER_WALL = @"wall";
NSString *const VK_PER_GROUPS = @"groups";
NSString *const VK_PER_MESSAGES = @"messages";
NSString *const VK_PER_NOTIFICATIONS = @"notifications";
NSString *const VK_PER_STATS = @"stats";
NSString *const VK_PER_ADS = @"ads";
NSString *const VK_PER_OFFLINE = @"offline";
NSString *const VK_PER_NOHTTPS = @"nohttps";
NSString *const VK_PER_EMAIL = @"email";
```

like this

```
[VKSdk authorize:@[VK_PER_EMAIL, VK_PER_FRIENDS, VK_PER_MESSAGES] revokeAccess:YES forceOAuth:NO inApp:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use this link.
Description in russian.

https://vk.com/developers.php?oid=-1&p=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9